# insert 2 array value to new array with new key

Tags: php, arrays, merge

i have below two array :

```
Array 1
(
  [0] => Daughter
  [1] => Daughter
  [2] => Son
)
Array 2
(
  [0] => Nitu
  [1] => ritu
  [2] => ramesh
)
```

and i want different array for each key as below :

```
Array(
 "relation"  => Daughter
 "name"      => Nitu
 )

 Array(
 "relation"  => Daughter
 "name"      => ritu
 )

  Array(
 "relation"  => Son
 "name"      => ramesh
 )
```

above array 1 & array 2 can be long as per user input. so i want to insert value to new array in loop dynamically.

Comment: heard of `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$Aarray1 = Array 
(
  "0" => "Daughter",
  "1" => "Daughter",
  "2" => "Son"
);
$Aarray2 = Array 
(
  "0" => "Nitu",
  "1" => "ritu",
  "2" => "ramesh"
);

   foreach($Aarray1 as $key=>$val)
   {
       $new_array[$key]["relation"] = $val;
       $new_array[$key]["name"] = $Aarray2[$key];
   }
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/HgRf4)**

Comment: also pls guide me to generate output in single dimension :), like as my output above.

Comment: @SantoshBohara please check my edit this now holds the single dimensional array inside the foreach loop

Comment: this is generating output for 3rd one only, what about value of 0 & 1 from array1 & array2.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to loop through your array and store it in a variable `$result`.

Try this:

```
$array1 = array('Daughter', 'Daughter','Son');
$array2 = array('Nitu', 'Ritu', 'Ramesh');
foreach ($array1 as $k => $arr1) {
    $result[] = array(
        'relation' => $arr1, 
        'name' => $array2[$k]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$arrayFirst = Array("0" => "Daughter", "1" => "Daughter", "2" => "Son");
$arraySecond = Array("0" => "Nitu","1" => "ritu","2" => "ramesh");

foreach($arrayFirst as $key=>$value)
{
    $new_array[$key]["relation"] = $value;
    $new_array[$key]["name"] = $arraySecond[$key];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are trying to search for **array_combine**

You can check the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)